# how to add multiple selected cell comment add in office js?

Tags: office-js

I am working with office js but unable to add multiple selected cells comments. I have already read office js document but can't find a similar solution which I want. if I have selected a single cell below code work properly.

```
   await Excel.run(async (context) => {
                 const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        
          const comment = context.workbook.comments.getItemByCell(range);

          comment.content = "add comment";

          await context.sync();  
});
```

I am a beginner for office js and following code get address Sheet1!I4:K4.so does I have manually loop through adding a comment like I4, J4, K4 but it not better way. if I am wrong please correct me thank you.

```
try {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    try {
      var range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
      range.load(["address"]);
      return context.sync().then(function () {
        const addString = range.address;
       //Sheet1!I4:K4

      });
    } catch (error) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-empty
      if (error.code == Excel.ErrorCodes.itemNotFound) {
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    }

  });
} catch (error) {
  ErrorProvider.getInstance().notify(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want. See the code below:

```
async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let wb = context.workbook
    let ws = wb.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet()
    let rang = wb.getSelectedRange()
    rang.load("rowCount, columnCount")
    await context.sync()
    let rangRowCount = rang.rowCount
    let rangColCount = rang.columnCount
    let rangeAddresses = []
    for (let i = 0; i < rangRowCount; i++) {
      {
        for (let j = 0; j < rangColCount; j++)
        {
          let newRang = rang.getCell(i,j)
          rangeAddresses.push(newRang.load("address"))
        }
      }

    }
    await context.sync()
    rangeAddresses.forEach(e => {
      wb.comments.add(e.address, "This is a comment")
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you @beyphy. 
However, this works is only static selected cells. Ex: start to address anything like A2, B4, D6 and ending address anything like D2, E4, H6.
However I need to develop dynamic selected cell by users.
can you please suggest me or give the solution of dynamic multiple cell selection.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood your initial post. I've updated my comment with new code.